# Is the map $\bigsqcup_{w } \frac{BwP}{P} = \frac{GL_n(\mathbb{C})}{P} \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ via $bwP \mapsto bw$ a morphism of algebraic varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, fiber-bundles

Let $G = GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, $P \subseteq G$ a parabolic subgroup, and consider the decomposition $\frac{G}{P} = \bigsqcup_{w \in W^P} \frac{BwP}{P}$ where $W \cong S_n$ is the Weyl group of $G$, $W_P$ is the subset of $W$ associated to $P$ and $W^P = \frac{W}{W_P}$ and we consider $w \in W^P$ of minimal length in the above decomposition. Define $\phi: \frac{G}{P}  = \bigsqcup_{w \in W^P} \frac{BwP}{P} \to G$ via $\phi(bwP) = bw$. My question is:

> Is the map $\phi(bwP) = bw$ a morphism of algebraic varieties? Is it continuous in the Zariski topology?

$\textbf{Motivation}$: I am trying to show that the map $\frac{G}{B} \to \frac{G}{P}$ via $gB \mapsto gP$ is a fiber bundle. I have not been able to prove this directly, but a Theorem in Steenrod's book $\textit{Topology of Fibre Bundles}$ was suggested as helpful.

Let $G$ be a topological group and $H$ a closed subgroup. Let $x_0$ denote the coset $P \in \frac{G}{P}$, and suppose $V$ is an open neighborhood of $x_0$ in $\frac{G}{P}$. In Chapter 7, Steenrod defines a $\textit{local cross section}$ of $P$ in $G$ to be a continuous map $f: V \to G$ such that $p(f(xP)) = xP$ where $p: G \to \frac{G}{P}$ is the canonical quotient (I think this is called being locally constant?).

Theorem 3 in this chapter states that if we have closed subgroups $B \subset P \subset G$ and if $P$ admits a local cross section the the map from $\frac{G}{B} \to \frac{G}{P}$ via $gB \to gP$ is a fiber bundle.

Taking $V$ to be the whole space $G/P$ I believe my map above $\phi(bwP) = bw$ is a local cross section. I am not sure how to show that it is an morphism of algebraic varieties, or that it is continuous in the Zariski topology. Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The map doesn't seem to be well defined, unless there's some special way you select $b$.

Comment: I think I was rushing too much on that, you're right that is an issue. I need to either put more work into this map or try a different approach.